# How to use ajax with tinyMCE HTML editor to send source code

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am using tinymce HTML editor to create an Editor which will be able to store the HTML script into Database and then retrieve from there to create blog Posts.
The problem occurring is that tinymce provides a Plugin called "code"(to view the source code(HTML) of written content) which contains a statement

```
a.getContent(); //To get the source code
```

I want to use this statement as ajax query to send the query string at backend side.
But I don't know how can I use this statement and ajax together .
here is the code plugin of Tinymce(I have changed a bit for my testing purpose)

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("code",function(a){
function b(){var b=a.windowManager.open({
    title:"Source code",
    body:
    {
        type:"textbox",
        name:"code",multiline:!0,
        minWidth:a.getParam("code_dialog_width",600),
        minHeight:a.getParam("code_dialog_height",Math.min(tinymce.DOM.getViewPort().h-200,500)),
        spellcheck:!1,style:"direction: ltr; text-align: left"
    },
    onSubmit:function(b){
    a.focus(),
    a.undoManager.transact(function(){
    a.setContent(b.data.code)}),
    a.selection.setCursorLocation(),
    a.nodeChanged()
}});
console.log(a.getContent({source_view:0}))}
a.addCommand("mceCodeEditor",b),
a.addButton("code",{icon:"code",tooltip:"Source code",onclick:b}),
a.addMenuItem("code",{icon:"code",text:"Source code",context:"tools",onclick:b})});
```

My Webpage contain this

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinymce.init({
 selector: '#myTextarea',
 theme: 'modern',
 width: 600,
 height: 300,
 plugins:
  'code' });
</script>
</head>
 <body>
 <div id="myTextarea"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using jquery, or you only want native javascript?

Comment: also using jquery to handle other things but how can i implement with this i don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tinyMCE.get('myTextarea').getContent()` will give you the data which is inside the editor.

Now use `$.ajax` to send the data to the server.

See the code example:

JS Bin link : http://jsbin.com/giruro/edit?html,js,output

The `"SEE" button` justs alerts the data, and the `"SEND" button` sends an AJAX request to the server with the tinyce editor content.

```js
$("#target1").click(function() {
  alert(tinyMCE.get('myTextarea').getContent());
});
$("#target2").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "foobar",
      data: {
        data: tinyMCE.get('myTextarea').getContent()
      }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='tinymce.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#myTextarea',
      theme: 'modern',
      width: 600,
      height: 300,
      plugins: 'code'
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="target">SEE</button>
  <button id="target">SEND</button>
  <div id="myTextarea"></div>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I was just scratching my mind from 4 days that how it will be possible but you helped me alot :) . I haven't tried it yet but I am damn sure you that you will be right.

Comment: I can't until i don't reach a milestone

Comment: i wud as soon as i get the score

Answer (score 0):

```
//your ajax call
$.ajax({
   type:'POST'
   data:$('#myTextarea').tinyMCE().getContent()
})
```